# Change ContentControl content with button click

Tags: windows-8, contentcontrol

I have a ContentControl which is bound to this DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class PropertyPageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null) return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);

        var contentControl = (ContentControl)container;
        var templateKey = (string)item;

        return (DataTemplate)contentControl.Resources[templateKey];
    }
}
```

How can I change the loaded resource in the ContentControl with a button click? I can not call the method directly because it is protected...

Answer (score 0):

Since the item is a string, the ContentControl's Content is a string. All you need to do is change the ContentControl's Content to the desired string.

Comment: Okay thank ou that works but how can I change the Content from an other Class?

Comment: @Cilenco That is hard to answer as it is really an application architecture question, but the standard practice is to create a class to act as the view model for the page your in with a property that your ContentControl's Content would bind to. Please take a look at this sample and see if this helps: [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5)